# I have a bug in my Ajax code that has two scripts in it and cannot locate it

Tags: ajax

The barrating on the page works as it should - visually.
When clicking a star, nothing happens, no ajax call.
I have yesterday realized the collision of the two scripts, and that should now be solved by $b.
But, my PHP page does not show me the rating value as expected.

I thought I might have the wrong reference for the Ajax call, massage-form/massage-rating, nothing works.
I'm a bit lost, been looking at it for several days now, might have stared me blind at it.
To me, it looks correct but, with no result, it is not correct.

Been trying several solutions on the second script, on.click etc. to no avail.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-stars.css">
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $b = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<form id="massage-form">
    <select id="massage-rating" name="stars" method="POST">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" type="submit" type="button" id="submit-button">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $b(function() {
        $("#massage-rating").barrating({
        theme: 'css-stars'
        });
        $('select').barrating();
        $('select').barrating('set', 4);
        showSelectedRating: true;
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#massage-form").on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './review/create_star_rating.php',
            data: formData,
                success: function(response){
                    window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()},1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

I expect this PHP code to give me a visual value, but that does not happen.

```
if(isset($_POST['rating'])){
    $rating = $_POST['rating'];
    echo $rating;
    break;
```

not complete code, just this specific snippet.

Any pointers/solutions will be greatly appreciated. I do assume this has the simplest of solutions, but I cannot see it.

Relatively new to Ajax, but reading a lot anyhow.

I got inspired by this: https://www.phpzag.com/star-rating-system-with-ajax-php-and-mysql/

Comment: **Do not follow phpzag.com tutorials!** They are advocating bad programming practices and their code samples are full of security problems. Please learn about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) first.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax code fixed,

works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css-stars.css">
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>

<form id="massage-form" Method="POST">
    <select id="rating" name="stars">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#rating").barrating({
        theme: 'css-stars',
        initialRating: 4,
        onSelect: function(value){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: './review/create_star_rating.php',
//              dataType: 'json',
                data: {number: value},
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert('Thank you for your rating');
//                  alert(jqXHR.responseText);
//                  window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()},1000);
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    alert(xhr.status +" :" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Now to fix my php code to work as intended, but that was in the pipeline anyways.
I leave this here, if others have similar issues.